# Why does React Native jump to top of page when input box receives focus?

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the oddest behavior on code that I didn't write (inherited from a colleague). I have never seen this before.

In React Native, when I click on one component's box, sometimes it jumps to the top of the component (it's wrapped by a Scrollview). Other times the view stays put, as it's supposed to. What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you make a small code example that demonstrates this?

Comment: I'm not sure what to post - I'm stepping through the issue one step at a time in the VS Code debugger and it seems to happen somewhere within the function _tickCallback() in "<node_internals>/internal/process/next_tick.js". It does not appear to be triggered by any code any of our engineers wrote and it doesn't show up on our Android version of the app (same code re-used for iOS).